# Detect mobile device browsers, not only screen width

Tags: css, browser-detection, mobile-devices

I know that I can activate some styling with media query like that:

```
/* Magic for mobile devices */
@media (max-width: 33em ) 
{
}
```

however I don't really like this approach since it checks only against screen width.
I found this `java script` code for detecting mobile browsers and now I need the same check with `CSS`

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // some code..
}
```

Is there a `CSS` equivalent of this js?

Comment: How do you define "mobile"? What about 7", 10", or 20" tablets?

Comment: @SLaks That's why I'm asking this question. Currently `@media` offers a check against screen width. What if there is a 17" tablet and 17" PC screen. I would like to show the mobile version of my CSS on the tablet and the desktop version on the PC. If there is a CSS check against mobile browsers this will allow me to show the appropriate styles.

Comment: That's my point.  You probably shouldn't be doing that in the first place.  Why is the mobile version more suitable?

Comment: Because when you are using tablet you have to use your fingers to click on a button, so for the user would be better to have larger buttons. Doesn't matter if he is using 17" tablet or 7" - still have to touch the button.

Comment: What about Windows 8 touch desktops & convertible laptops?

Comment: http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/

Comment: Yep you are right about Windows 8 touch desktops, I'll have a look on this article.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="handheld">
```

This will target small or handheld devices.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET themes, so the only CSS reference is for Jquery Mobile's CSS. How can I apply your answer to my case?

Comment: @AntonBelev Sorry I don't have the answer to that, i'm not familiair with asp.net. But what your asking is another question, so it's best to make a new post for that.

Comment: You can use a media query eg: @media handheld { .myclass {width: 300px;} }